# Define a $2 \times 2$ matrix that is the lower $2 \times 2$ block in $A$ (Matlab)

Tags: matrices, matlab

First of all, on this Matlab exercise sheet that I am currently working through what does the term 'the lower $2 \times 2$ block' mean in the question below?

$A = 
\left[\begin{array}\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}\right]$,

Define a $2 \times 2$ matrix that is the lower $2 \times 2$ block in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the wording; it is the submatrix $\left[\begin{array}\
5 & 6 \\
8 & 9 \\
\end{array}\right]$. In Matlab, you need to say $A(2:3,2:3)$ to get the submatrix.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of `A` can vary, you can always get the lower 2x2 block as such:

```
A(end-1:end,end-1:end)
```

Note that this always works as long as the width and height of `A` are both at least 2.